# algorithms to predict whether two people will cooperate or not

Tags: machine-learning

I am working on a problem that required me to predict whether two providers in the market will cooperate with each other or not. We only have providers' geographic info and case numbers that they have worked with. Thus, if two providers share a same case number, they have cooperated before.

Initially, I tried logistic regression approach to predict whether two providers will cooperate or not. The problem with this is the training data size will increase a lot, since we need to pair each possible providers as one training data. Thus, 10 providers will result in a 10*9 rows of training data.

I also did some research on recommendation system, but I am not sure if this is the right approach or not. Can anyone give me some suggestions that how I should do my research? What kind of approaches may be possible there?

Comment: Are you looking for actual algorithm or some platform/service to solve this problem ?

Comment: Why size of the data is a problem? As far as I understand, the matrix will be sparse.

Comment: @PhagunBaya I am looking for some algorithm.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski For the provider level data, it is not that sparse.

Comment: A small note here. For 10 providers you don't have 10*9 rows but 'only' `9+8+...+1` rows since you don't need (I guess) data for both `provider_1 & provider_2` and `provider_2 & provider_1`.

Comment: Your features are only geographic info? Like distance between each two providers? Do you have anything else?